# Android app publishing: can not install apk

Tags: android, apk, publishing, installation

I created a simple android app that starts an activity when button is clicked.
It runs properly on emulator
I exported it using eclipse export wizard

Project
Folder size = 1.2MB
APK file size = 179KB

My phone
Internal free memory = 16MB
Memory card free memory = 1.5GB

Issue
but now when I try to launch this apk file on my phone it says "Out of space:Free up some space and try again"

what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried running on the phone within eclipse without going through the export process?

Comment: Yes I tried to do that but driver for phone was not installed on my computer and windows can't find any from web so I couldn't run it on phone for debugging.

Comment: _what should I do?_ *"Free up some space and try again"* --- That's exactly what you should do. The system preserves some free space in internal memory for its own usage. So, that 16MB, although a lot "bigger" than 1.2MB may not be enough.

Comment: Thanks it works I had to free up 25MB to install it. although it was a 600kb app.